# Image upload continues after uploading all of their data

Tags: telegram

I upload some images to a Telegram channel. They're about 10000 files. I choose them to be grouped and compressed. They're splitted into groups with 10 images each. After taking a reasonable time to upload, I'll see that some of them have no sign on them which means that their upload is complete. Some of them has tick sign on them, which means that their dad have been uploaded completely and the upload is being finalized by the Telegram servers. Some of them has the sign of x with a complete circle around it. I think it means that 100% of their data has been uploaded and we're in the last step before the tick sign.

BUT...

After I see that all of the images are in one of the three statuses, I see that the Telegram is uploading still something. I don't know what is this "something". I don't know what is it still uploading. It's about 24 hours that Telegram is uploading and no changes has been made in the status of the images! It's while the whole process of uploading could be complete in about an hour or even half an hour. I've a good link to Telegram servers and the speed of uploading is up to 3.2 mega bytes per second.

Once I tried just two images. I didn't group them. The pattern of x and circle appears after their data upload got completed. Telegram was still working on something and didn't change their status to completed or even tick. I got disappointed, but let Telegram still work on it. After about 15 minutes, I returned back to PC and found that the "work" is complete and the images got completed. What can I judge? Maybe Telegram is stealing some personal data from my computer before it reports them as completed?! What is really uploading after the whole images data upload is complete?!

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Client: The app telegram-desktop which was installed by apt install.

Comment: Feel free to report an issue at https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop but as it stands I'm voting for closing as this question is not about programming.

Comment: ok, sorry, i didn't know where to send.